# PHP If not divisible by three add 1 to variable, if it is divisible by three then just divide it

Tags: php, if-statement, math

```
<?php $i = 0; ?>
<?php
    $count_posts = wp_count_posts();

    $published_posts = $count_posts->publish;

    if ($published_posts % 3 == 0) {
        $row_number = '(int) ($published_posts / 3)';
    }
    else {
        $row_number = '(int) ($published_posts / 3 ) + 1';
    };
?>
```

I'm trying to set it so that if the number of $published_posts is divisible by three, then set the variable $row_number to whatever the result of $published_posts divided by three is. But if the number of $published_posts is not evenly dividable by 3, then add 1 to it and set $row_number to the result of that.

Comment: Start by removing the quotes from around the code.

Comment: You have an extra semi-colon after your else `;?>`

Are you trying to add one if it's no divideable by 3 or do you want to add 1 UNTIL it is dividiable by 3?

Comment: I want to add one if it's not divisible by three without a remainder.

Comment: Or did you want the quotient `(posts+2)/3` resp. `(posts-1)/3+1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe that is all you wanted?

```
<?php
    $published_posts = rand(0, 100);
    print('Published posts = ' . $published_posts . "\n");
    $row_number = 0;

    if ($published_posts % 3 == 0) {
        print("divided by 3\n");
        $row_number = (int)($published_posts / 3);
    }
    else {
        print("added 1\n");
        $row_number = (int)($published_posts + 1);
    }
    print('row number = ' . $row_number);
?>
```